# How to fix taskbar with dark theme on has ambient colors on Kubuntu 22.04 or on KDE Plasma 5.24.7 in general?

Tags: kde, kubuntu

On Kubuntu 22.04 (KDE Plasma 5.24.7) the dark theme taskbar has ambient colors, How do I fix that?

To be clear the dark theme I am talking about is the one in the quick settings.

Picture of ambient colors:
[image]

Comment: There is no dark mode, only themes. Could you describe what you mean by "quick settings"?

Comment: @mashuptwice The settings at the home menu on the "System Settings" app and also they are are offically called "Quick Settings"

Comment: So, what is the name of the dark theme you are using? Would you mind also sharing a screenshot of the "ambient colors"?

Comment: @mashuptwice No, I wouldn't mind sharing a screenshot of the "ambient colors".

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are talking about the panels transparency.

On KDE >= 5.22 there is a setting for that:

```
Settings -> Workspace behaviour -> Desktop Effects
```

Where you find 3 options to control the transparency:

```
Background contrast 

Transparency

Blur
```

Comment: I could not find "Transparancy" but I found "Translucency" but that was already disabled